# Prove that each natural number has a multiple solely consisting of digits $0,1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that each natural number has a multiple solely consisting of digits $0,1$
I have really no idea for this!!

Comment: every number is divisible by 1... please sharp your question

Comment: @boaz I don't understand your comment. How do you use the fact that $n$ is divisible by $1$ to prove that some multiple of $n$ has a decimal representation containing only $0$'s and $1$'s?

Comment: Maybe look at the remainders when  $1,11,111,1111,11111$, and so on are divided by $m$. Then use the Pigeonhole Principle and it will be nearly all over.

Comment: The original form of the question was fine; your edit in response to boaz's comment was unnecessary and in fact made the question harder to understand, since $1$ is not a mulitple of most numbers.

Comment: you right bof...i thought he meant a factor

Comment: @AndréNicolas But your suggested numbers don't contain digit $0$! That technique looks for a limited part of such multiples

Comment: Hate to give it away entirely. There will be two different strings of $1$'s with the same remainder. Their **difference** is of the right shape and divisible by $m$.

Comment: If the number is coprime to $10$, then it is a factor of  number of all $1$s. Search our site with the buzzword *repunit* to find the argument. If your number has $2$s and $5$ as prime factors, zeros will be forced upon you. First multiply the number $n$ by complementary powers of $2$ and $5$ to get something of the form
$$2^a5^bn=10^km$$
where $\gcd(m,10)=1$. Added: Mind you, André's argument is even better.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the remainders when we divide $1,10,10^2,\cdots$ by $k$. We know that at least one of $0,1,\cdots, k-1$ appears infinitely many times. Let it be $r$. Then take $a_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots, k)$ such that
$$10^{a_i}\equiv r\pmod k$$
where $0\le a_1\lt a_2\lt \cdots\lt a_k$.

Now

> $$10^{a_i}+10^{a_2}+\cdots +10^{a_k}\ \ $$

Answer (score 0):

notice that it is suffices to prove it for prime numbers since the general assertion can be done using induction.